# Looping does not return the data

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

my code only loops once then return only one data. below is my code

```
def test():

for element_regFile in root.findall('country'):
    csvdataElement=[]

    filename=element_regFile.find('name')
    if filename != None:
        filename=filename.text
    else:
        filename='None'
    csvdataElement.append(filename)

    return csvdataElement
```

Then, i want to print the output of the function one by one as shown below:

```
print test()
>>>> [London]
>>>> [Paris]
```

The print statement will be outside the function

Below is my xml:

```
    ?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country >
        <name>London</name>
        <rank>1</rank>
        <abc>123</abc>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    </country>
        <country >
        <name>Paris</name>
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2010</year>
        <gdppc>68000</gdppc>
    </country>
</data>
```

It should return London and Paris. But unfortunately, it only return London.

Comment: A `return` statement ends the execution of the function call and "returns" the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is indentation problem. `print` statement should have same indentation like `for` :

```
for element_regFile in root.findall('country'):
    csvdataElement=[]

    filename=element_regFile.find('name')
    if filename != None:
        filename=filename.text
    else:
        filename='None'
    csvdataElement.append(filename)

print(csvdataElement)
```

Comment: I did change the indentation, but it return Paris. Not both

Comment: @vause: Added `print` statement instead of `return`. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

```
for element_regFile in root.findall('country'):
    csvdataElement=[]
    filename=element_regFile.find('name')
    if filename != None:
        filename=filename.text
    else:
        filename='None'
    csvdataElement.append(filename)
    print(csvdataElement)
```

Comment: it shows both name; London and Paris. But the data is in one list; [London,Paris]. I would like to make it in a difference list ; [London] [Paris]

Comment: @vause You mean nested list. something like this `[["London"], ["Paris"]]`

Comment: No, in a difference list. First, it will return [London] , the it will return [Paris]. Sorry , im new this Python thingy.

Comment: Can you provide the output you want from your test `function`?

Comment: I already provide the output in my question above.

Comment: @vause Anyway I  have updated the above answer. But there is nothing to do with appending item into the list and printing it, Because there should be only one item at each iteration.

Comment: I see, it is impossible to use return statement? Thanks a lot

Comment: @vause Yup A return statement ends the execution of the function call and "returns" the result. You can use but this is not the case you wanted.